# Changing old C for loop to new Swift loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, for-loop

I have an old Xcode 7.3 Swift 2 code. I need to change these two for loops to the new swift 3 for loop syntax.

```
fileprivate func collapseSubItemsAtIndex(_ index : Int) {

    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    let parent = self.findParent(index)
    checkCurrentLanguage()

    if lang.isEqual(to: "en")
    {
        //For loop 1
        for (var i = index + 1; i <= index + self.engsubItems[parent].count; i += 1 ){
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
        }
        self.engtableview.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        self.engtotal  -= self.engsubItems[parent].count

    }
    else{
        //For loop 2
        for (var i = index + 1; i <= index + self.subItems[parent].count; i += 1 ){
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
        }
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        self.total  -= self.subItems[parent].count

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `lang == "en"`?

Comment: @Sulthan i just received this code and they need to update it all to swift 3. There are many coding mistakes that i still didn't fix or refine.

Answer (score 1):

```
let count = self.engsubItems[parent].count

let rowsToDelete = ((index + 1) ... (index + count))
     .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
self.engtableview.deleteRows(at: rowsToDelete, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
self.engtotal -= count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in (index+1)...(index + self.engsubItems[parent].count) {
    ...
}
for i in (index+1)...(index + self.subItems[parent].count) {
    ...
}
```